# Shortcut to quickly run a project from a Javascript in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

I've been using dreamweaver for years;  I have just got WebStorm 6.0.2.

I am wondering if there's a way to set a shortcut that runs (HTML-CCS-JS) project in Chrome or IE from a specifique Javascript code (while you're editing js files), just like pressing F12 in dreamWeaver.

Answer (score 0):

To have the application opened in a specific browser of your choice, choose `View | Web preview` on the main menu or press `Alt+F2`. Then select the desired browser from the pop-up menu.

Comment: Yeah i know this feature , but this will open the current page in the browser not the head HTML page . Imagine that u have a js file that ur editing , in dreamweaver when u press F12 it opens the HTML page that calls this js file, but in WebStorm , it opens the JS file in browser , u'll get only the texts of the Js .

Answer (score 0):

Actually , this feature doesn't exist yet . I posted a similar topic to there technical team , and they said that this feature is on hold , and will be released soon .

The idea is to open an HTML5 page and be able to edit & see the related JS / CSS files , and from any file of these , you can run the project (the root HTML) .

Since this question isn't really important , i'll delete it in like 1 week .

Regards.